# ReactJS - Storing API data in state

Tags: reactjs

New to React and JS in general so I apologize for the simplistic nature of this question.

I'm attempting to store a single child's name from my API in React's state but I must be doing something incorrectly with the JSON as this state is never updated.

If someone could explain what I'm doing incorrect and the best way to accomplish this, I'd very much appreciate it. My code almost mirrors this but I can't seem to figure out whats wrong here.

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Child from '../../Components/Child/Child'

class MyKids extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  kidsName: '',
};
}
componentDidMount() {


fetch( 'http://localhost:3001/api/kids' )
.then( response => response.json())
.then(data => this.setState({kidsName: data[0].name}));

}

render() {

  const { kidsName } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className = 'col-sm-12'>
          <ul>
            <p>{ kidsName }</p>
            <Child
              kidsName={ kidsName }
              />
          </ul>
    </div>
);
}
}


export default MyKids;
```

JSON Response:

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"_id":"5b10610c827ea427b05581b9","name":"Nick"},{"_id":"5b115bc8827ea427b05581bb","name":"Trevor"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the processing of the second `then` in the `fetch` should be:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch( 'http://localhost:3001/api/kids' )
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({kidsName: data.data[0].name}));
}
```

For clarity you might change it for:

```
componentDidMount() {
     fetch( 'http://localhost:3001/api/kids' )
         .then( response => response.json())
         .then(result => this.setState({kidsName: result.data[0].name}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here:

```
.then(data => this.setState({kidsName: data[0].name}));
```

This should be

```
.then(res => this.setState({kidsName: res.data[0].name}));
```

instead, because `data` in the first snippet has the shape `{ data: [...] }`.

Comment: should someone update or write new answer to use newer async/await? Lyubomir, feel free to, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the answer to use newest async/await without mixing older Promise .then syntax as seen in other answers.

```
const testAsync = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/kids', { method: "GET" });
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({kidsName: data[0].name}));
        console.log("response Json", responseJson);
      } else {
        console.log(response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error found", e);
    }
  };
```